# Comma in between numbers

Tags: visualforce

i need comma in between my number 
eg- 1000 --> 1,000

i m attaching the controller and vf page for this

```
public List<BarData> getOpportunityTarget(){
    Integer CurrentMonth = Date.Today().Month();
    Decimal total = 0.0; 
    TargetList = new List<BarData>();
    if(MonthlyTargetMap.get(currentMonth) != null){
        if(OpportunityList.size()>0){   
            for(Opportunity objOpportunity : OpportunityList){
                if(objOpportunity.StageName == 'Approved' && objOpportunity.Amount != null && objOpportunity.closeDate.Month() == CurrentMonth){
                    total += objOpportunity.Amount;
                }
            }
            TargetList.add(new BarData('Closed',total.setScale(0)));        
            TargetList.add(new BarData('Target',MonthlyTargetMap.get(currentMonth).setScale(0)));            
        }else{
            TargetList.add(new BarData('Closed',0));        
            TargetList.add(new BarData('Target',MonthlyTargetMap.get(currentMonth).setScale(0)));            
        }
    }                                    
    return TargetList;
```

---

Vf Page

```
<div class="sections" >                               
    <div class="graph-section">                       
        <h2 align="center">Closed v/s Running Target </h2><br/><br/> 
        <apex:chart height="300" width="400" data="{!OpportunityTarget}">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data" grid="true" minimum="0" />
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name">
                <apex:chartLabel rotate="315" font="bold 13px Helvetica"/>
            </apex:axis>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="name" yField="data" colorSet="#99ccff">
                <apex:chartTips height="20" width="150" />
                <apex:chartLabel field="data" display="outside" orientation="horizontal" font="bold 12px Helvetica" />                                    
            </apex:barSeries>
        </apex:chart>                                            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rendererFn` attribute available for `<apex:chartLabel`to achieve this. `rendererFn` attribute takes a JavaScript function and re-render the label based on the output of the function. You have to modify the label and return it as the function output. Please refer to the example below.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="BarChartController">
    <apex:chart height="400" width="400" data="{!employees}">
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="salary" title="Salary" minimum="0" maximum="5000">
            <apex:chartLabel rendererFn="labelRenderer"/>
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Name"/>
        <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="name" yField="salary"/>
    </apex:chart>
    <script>
    function labelRenderer(klass){
        return (klass.format()+"");
    }
    Number.prototype.format = function(n, x) {
        var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + (x || 3) + '})+' + (n > 0 ? '\\.' : '$') + ')';
        return this.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~n)).replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&,');
    };    
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class BarChartController {
    public class Employee{
        public String name {get; set; }
        public Integer salary {get; set;}
        public String fsalary {get; set;}
        Employee(String name, Integer salary){
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.fsalary = name+salary;
        }
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        List<Employee> lstEm = new List<Employee>();
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee1',1000));
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee2',2000));
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee3',3000));
        return lstEm;
    }
}
```

Generated Chart

[image]

Comment: This is a much better, well constructed answer!

Comment: thanx for Help!!!! It Works